# Excel Conditional Formatting - format cell based on row number AND formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally format cells individually that are above a certain value AND on an even row number. I can perform these tasks separately, but the AND function will not work. I believe it is due to Excel trying "compute" a range comparison inside the AND, and it produces 0.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula

```
=AND(B2>0.5,MOD(ROW(),2)=0)
```

and apply to range `$B$2:$C$4`

[image]

Comment: Why do I need to reference an individual cell here whereas for the first example I show, the range works?

Comment: Range works, but not the way you think. In the first example, CF takes the first cell from the range and compares it to 0.5, i.e. cell ```B2``` uses the formula ```B2:C4>0.5 => B2>0.5 => TRUE```, cell ```C2``` uses ```C2:D4>0.5 => C2>0.5 => FALSE```, etc. In the third example, CF takes the entire range, divides it into cells, and compares each to 0.5, then returns the result to the ```AND``` function, i.e. cell ```F2``` uses ```AND(F2:G4>0.5,MOD(ROW(),2)=0) => AND(F2>0.5,G2>0.5 ... F4>0.5,G4>0.5, MOD(ROW(),2)=0) => AND(TRUE, FALSE ... FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) => FALSE```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the conditional formatting syntax a lot better now. Cheers.